# MVC authorization not working when mixed with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I have developed an **MVC + Angularjs** application, a mixed application, and Angular application's first page is my HomeController's Index view as the starting point and now I want to authorize the home page's Index view, but now my MVC authorization attribute is not working and even using with authorization attribute I am able to directly open the Home page.

I need this to be authorized and then that authorized person should open the door to Angular application.

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {           
        return View();
    }
```

and this is the Index View, and the starting point of my angularjs application, and other HTML pages are embedded in this view

```
<div class="row">
 <div ng-view>
 </div>
</div>
```

Kindly help me in solving this, and point me what I am doing wrong or I have implemented things wrong. Here is my HomeController's Index action with authorize attribute,

Comment: you haven't provided any information here that would be useful to others in determining why your code isn't working.  please see how to create a [mcve] of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

if you are using ui router you can add this to your app.js

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
                $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event,
                        next, current) {
                        if ($rootScope.authenticated == false)
                            //your code
                });
            })
```

For every location change you can check for authentication!